# Problem with changing the fomat of the text on a html website

Tags: html, macos

Why doesn't the change of format in TextEdit show on the website? I'm using macOS.
[image: TextEdit]

[image: webpage]

Is it a problem with macOS system? Or is there a special way to type </? I'm clueless...

As a total beginner, I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet along with the output? StackOverflow has a separate feature for rendering JS/CSS/HTML snippets in the post itself.

Comment: Don't edit with TextEdit. It's same as on Windows editing it with Word. Use SublimeEditor or some other raw text editor

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Work with HTML documents in TextEdit on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/textedit/txted0b6cd61/mac)

Comment: @Justin I don't think the editor holds any relevance for this problem.

Comment: @kush Then write your code with Word, go ahead. It will encode `<` to `&lt;`

Comment: @Justin The file is saved with HTML extension, so I am assuming it must be saved as plain text

Comment: @Alex you can press `CMD+SHIFT+T` or click `Format > Make Plain Text`. save and refresh your browser

Comment: @kush Thank you for letting me know the features! I got the answer so quick even before the editing. I'll try it next time!

Comment: @caramba Thank you! This a very clear instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem I faced too on macOS. By default, all documents created on TextEdit are Rich Text Documents. To convert them to plain text, press `cmd+shift+T`, which will convert the file to plain text. Then, save the file as .htm or .html.